# Can Windows 7 be installed on a Toshiba Netbook that says "Designed for Windows XP"?

Tags: windows-7, netbook, toshiba-laptop

My friend bought a Toshiba netbook more than an year ago. The netbook came with an XP install on single partition. It also has a tag/sticker saying ***"Designed for Windows XP"***. The machine has a 1 GB memory and an Atom processor.

The question is whether or not I can install Windows 7 on the same system.

Comment: For what it's worth: I have an Atom-powered UMPC (like a netbook, without a keyboard or lid) with 1GB of RAM, and it was 'designed for XP'. I installed Win7 Ultimate on it, and it runs as good or better than XP did.  But I think it's only bearable, on the 1GB RAM, because it has an SSD drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Download and install the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20) on the Toshiba, it will generate a report on your hardware and installed software and make recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

It will install and it will run okay. Your main hassle will be drivers. You may need to turn off some flashy features (like Aero) and I would recommend upgrading the RAM to at least 1.5 GB or 2 if the hardware is capable.

If you don't have a restore disk for it, take a snapshot/backup of the HDD as it stands now. You may find yourself wanting to go back to XP.

Answer (score 1):

After having to replace a failed hard drive, I put Windows 7 Professional on an Acer netbook with 1GB RAM; I let the install run automatically. I haven't turned off Aero or anything else yet it still works fine.